# How can nheqmine suspiciously run at 400% non-stop on a new EC2 instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I just setup an AWS EC2 instance and deployed some fairly simple code to it using Ansible. I then noticed something super strange, the CPU was a 400% and a program called 'nheqminer_cpu_x' was causing the issue.  It wouldn't stop running.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas on what could have caused that?  This is an Ubuntu 16x t2.xlarge box.

Thanks,

Comment: That is a "zcash" miner - if you didn't run it then you've been hacked.

Comment: Yep I figured as much.  I created the instance from an old image so it may have carried over from there.  Exposing port 22 and 443 only though so it's pretty strange. Anything else I can do besides maybe changing to non-standard ports?